# Phenomenon or phrase describing the understanding of words out of context

Tags: terminology, etymology

E.g. The phrase 'I love you' is common. If the word 'love' was replaced by an unrelated word (i.e. 'radiator') then the sentence 'I radiator you' would be meaningless.

But if the word radiator was then used repeatedly and consistently instead of love (i.e. 'I was in radiator with him and he radiated me') it wouldn't be too difficult to understand what was being communicated. Ditto for other words and phrases and their variations.

Is there any term or phenomenon that describes the ability to understand such disrupted communication based on our understanding of context?

Comment: Lots. One is _Metaphor_.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I'm looking for though. Entirely possible no such specific phrase exists!

Comment: @Will Yes, this phenomenon is known as *frozgarbling*. Orbit will be if you’re persistent enough ;)